# on duplicate key update, set the max limit to how much it will update before error

Tags: php, mysql, max, on-duplicate-key

This is what I have right now

```
"INSERT INTO `table`(`count`, `time`) VALUES ('1','$datetime')\
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1";
```

Everything works great but I'm trying to limit to how much count can increase by. For example, that script should run until count is at 5 then it should produce an error instead. How can I achieve this?